# Pig Error 1066, Backend error : -1; NegativeArraySizeException; UDF, joda-time, HBase

Tags: java, hbase, apache-pig, jodatime, user-defined-functions

> I'm getting an exception from a Pig script and haven't been able to nail down the cause. I'm fairly new to Pig & have searched for
>   various topics based on the exception I'm getting but haven't been
>   able to find anything meaningful.  From the grunt shell & log I've
>   looked for different variations of these -    unable to read pigs
>   manifest file   java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1   ERROR 1066:
>   Unable to open iterator for alias F. Backend error : -1
>
> I'm using Hadoop version 2.0.0-cdh4.6.0 & Pig version 0.11.0, running
>   from the Grunt shell.
>
> My Pig script reads a file, does some manipulation on the data
>   (including calling a Java UDF), joins to an HBase table, then DUMPs
>   the output. Pretty simple.  I can DUMP the intermediate result (alias
>   B) and the data looks fine.
>
> I've tested the Java function from Pig using the same input file and
>   have seen it return values as I'd expect, and I've tested the function
>   locally outside the Pig script. The Java function is provided a number
>   of days from 01-01-1900 & uses joda-time v2.7 to return a Datetime.
>   Initially, the UDF was accepting a tuple as input. I've tried changing
>   the UDF input format to Byte and most recently String and casting to
>   Datetime in Pig upon returning, but am still getting the same error.
>
> When I change my Pig script merely to not call the UDF it works fine.
>   The NegativeArray error sounds like the data is out of whack for the
>   Dump, possibly from some kind of format issue, but I don't see how.
>
> Pig script

```
A = LOAD 'tst2_SplitGroupMax.txt' using PigStorage(',')  
as (id:bytearray, year:int, doy:int, month:int, dayOfMonth:int,  
 awh_minTemp:double, awh_maxTemp:double,  
 nws_minTemp:double, nws_maxTemp:double,  
 wxs_minTemp:double, wxs_maxTemp:double,  
 tcc_minTemp:double, tcc_maxTemp:double  
 ) ;  

register /import/pool2/home/NA1000APP-TPSDM/ejbles/Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;  

B = FOREACH A GENERATE id as msmtid, SUBSTRING(id,0,8) as gridid, SUBSTRING(id,9,20) as msmt_days,  
 year, doy, month, dayOfMonth,  
 CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT((chararray)year,'-'),CONCAT((chararray)month,'-')),(chararray)dayOfMonth) as msmt_dt,  
 ToDate(monutil.geoloc.GridIDtoDatetime(id)) as func_msmt_dt,  
 awh_minTemp, awh_maxTemp,  
 nws_minTemp, nws_maxTemp,  
 wxs_minTemp, wxs_maxTemp,  
 tcc_minTemp, tcc_maxTemp  
 ;  

E = LOAD 'hbase://wxgrid_detail' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage  
 ('loc:country, loc:fips, loc:l1 ,loc:l2, loc:latitude, loc:longitude',  
 '-loadKey=true -caster=HBaseBinaryConverter')  
 as (wxgrid:bytearray, country:chararray, fips:chararray, l1:chararray, l2:chararray,  
   latitude:double, longitude:double);  

F = join B by gridid, E by wxgrid;  

DUMP F;  --- This is where I get the exception
```

> Here's an excerpt from what's returned in the Grunt shell -
>   2015-06-15 12:23:24,204 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure. 2015-06-15 12:23:24,205 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - job job_201502081759_916870 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs 2015-06-15 12:23:24,205 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 100% complete 2015-06-15 12:23:24,221 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR: -1 2015-06-15
>   12:23:24,221 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil -
>   1 map reduce job(s) failed! 2015-06-15 12:23:24,223 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - unable to read pigs
>   manifest file 2015-06-15 12:23:24,224 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:
>
> HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt
>   Features
>   2.0.0-cdh4.6.0          na1000app-tpsdm 2015-06-15 12:22:39     2015-06-15 12:23:24     HASH_JOIN
>
> Failed!
>
> Failed Jobs: JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
>   job_201502081759_916870 A,B,E,F HASH_JOIN       Message: Job failed!
>   hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/temp-238648079/tmp-1338617620,
>
> Input(s): Failed to read data from "hbase://wxgrid_detail" Failed to
>   read data from
>   "hdfs://nameservice1/user/na1000app-tpsdm/tst2_SplitGroupMax.txt"
>
> Output(s): Failed to produce result in
>   "hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/temp-238648079/tmp-1338617620"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_201502081759_916870
>
> 2015-06-15 12:23:24,224 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Failed! 2015-06-15 12:23:24,234 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator
>   for alias F. Backend error : -1 Details at logfile:
>   /import/pool2/home/NA1000APP-TPSDM/ejbles/pig_1434388844905.log
>
> And here's the log -
>   Backend error message
>   --------------------- java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.readByteArray(Bytes.java:148)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableSplit.readFields(TableSplit.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit.readFields(PigSplit.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:44)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:356)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:640)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Ch
>
> Pig Stack Trace
>   --------------- ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias F. Backend error : -1
>
> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable
>   to open iterator for alias F. Backend error : -1  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:828)     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:696)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:320)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)  at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.readByteArray(Bytes.java:148)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableSplit.readFields(TableSplit.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit.readFields(PigSplit.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:44)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:356)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:640)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)

Comment: id attribute signifies the no of days since 1-1-1970 or 1-1-1900 ?

Comment: > I asked the same thing when I started looking at this data. It's based off 1-1-1900.

Comment: Could you change your script to something more trivial untill it works? Either by changing the script, or by changing the UDF. That should allow you to pinpoint the source of the problem. -- For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).